# Почему программа не видит метод println()?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему программа не видит метод println()? IDE подкрашивает метод красным цветом и говорит, что такой переменной не существует.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in){
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            int a =scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println( "value = "+ a);
        }
    }
}
```

Компилятор пишет:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'println'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите код текстом, а не картинкой, чтобы другие могли скопировать. Также укажите полное сообщение об ошибке, которое выдает компилятор или IDE.

Comment: Учитесь читать сообщения компилятора об ошибках и понимать их причину, изучайте синтаксис. Задавать вопрос на StackOverflow про каждую синтаксическую ошибку -- довольно глупо. При активном написании кода их может появляться сотни в день (например, из-за опечаток), и исправляются они в большинстве случаев за пару тройку секунд.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что она находится внутри анонимного класса. Там допускаются только декларации полей, методов и типов.

Нужно поправить на это.

```
Scaner scaner = new Scaner(System.in);
System.out.println("");
char c = scaner.next().charAt(0);
```